# How to use Google analytics to track open rates, click rates in a email?

Tags: php, html, google-analytics, swiftmailer

I have read the document and there is a **track code** should be able to help me.
However, how can i actually use it to get the **open rates, url click rates**?

**For the open rates**:
I am using swiftmailer to send the mail, is it a way to add the track code (How? Since mail is plain html , no javascript or php is allowed) What i should do in the html/text mail template?

**For the url click rates**:
Is it separate from the mailing? that means i just have to add the link in the page i append in the mail.  However, are there ways to do it more automatically? For instance, when the mail is sent, i find the url and  add the track code for each link one by one?(But how can i create different track code using php?)

That 's lot of question, sorry.I am inexperience in it, Since it takes sometime to answer the question ,**any part of the answer is highly appreciated and i will vote up it**.  Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

The second part of your question:
If you are creating the email with php, you can easily add customized code to the url GET request, like this:
www.yoururl.com/...?yourvar=345
Then you pass the get variable to js (+validation).
Then on the page itself you can add customized event sending to analytics:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'name', value]);
```

Comment: push() is js function. _gaq is Analytics object. You can read about it here: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApi_gaq.html

Comment: don't forget to pass the value:  <script type="text/javascript"> var value=<? echo $_GET['yourvar']; ?>;</script> (validation to be added)