# Use Google analytics to track open rates of email?

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

Since email is a html page, and exclude all the javascript.

Therefore, how can i add the track code in the email ?

Also, is there any way to integrate the campaign result in my webpage(Which mean i do not hold the data, my system is only like a iframe that capture the screen from google analytic) ?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Google analytics to track open rates, click rates in a email?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9971444/how-to-use-google-analytics-to-track-open-rates-click-rates-in-a-email)

Comment: i also check that , but i saw the answer of click rate only, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Go here: http://pixelsite.info/new-pixel.php

1. They will let you generate a one-by-one pixel with your Google
   Analytics code through their form.
2. Next put that in your email html somewhere between the  tags.
3. If you're using this in gmail, which I am you can literally copy and paste the html from the browser (Cmd-A) in my case.

   1. Paste it into your email and you're good to roll!

Bonus: If you're sending out the template a couple of times make sure and turn on the 'Canned Responses' feature in labs, then you can save it as a canned response and easily re-insert it when you create a new message.

Hope this helps!